# How to show plotly chart in kedro

Tags: plotly, kedro

I am trying to use data science tool `kedro` according to [this tutorial](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/visualise_pipeline.html).
I followed the instruction(write config.yaml, node.py and pipeline.py etc) and do exactly the same as the documentation) and could run `kedro run` successfully.
And next step, I tried `kedro viz` and could show the pipelines but I cannot see plotly chart.
Here is the result of the visualization. Please see the left pane. I can see `Shuttle Passenger Capacity Plot` but it is not activated and plots does not show up.
[image]

Also, I set `conf/base/catalog.yaml` to output json file to load for plotly but I cannot see any in `08_reporting` directory. This could be the cause of the issue?

[image]

### Update

`nodes.py` and `pipeline.py` is located here.
[image]

**nodes.py**

```
import pandas as pd


def _is_true(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return x == "t"


def _parse_percentage(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    x = x.str.replace("%", "")
    x = x.astype(float) / 100
    return x


def _parse_money(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    x = x.str.replace("$", "").str.replace(",", "")
    x = x.astype(float)
    return x


def preprocess_companies(companies: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Preprocesses the data for companies.

    Args:
        companies: Raw data.
    Returns:
        Preprocessed data, with `company_rating` converted to a float and
        `iata_approved` converted to boolean.
    """
    companies["iata_approved"] = _is_true(companies["iata_approved"])
    companies["company_rating"] = _parse_percentage(companies["company_rating"])
    return companies


def preprocess_shuttles(shuttles: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Preprocesses the data for shuttles.

    Args:
        shuttles: Raw data.
    Returns:
        Preprocessed data, with `price` converted to a float and `d_check_complete`,
        `moon_clearance_complete` converted to boolean.
    """
    shuttles["d_check_complete"] = _is_true(shuttles["d_check_complete"])
    shuttles["moon_clearance_complete"] = _is_true(shuttles["moon_clearance_complete"])
    shuttles["price"] = _parse_money(shuttles["price"])
    return shuttles


def create_model_input_table(
        shuttles: pd.DataFrame, companies: pd.DataFrame, reviews: pd.DataFrame
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Combines all data to create a model input table.

    Args:
        shuttles: Preprocessed data for shuttles.
        companies: Preprocessed data for companies.
        reviews: Raw data for reviews.
    Returns:
        Model input table.

    """
    rated_shuttles = shuttles.merge(reviews, left_on="id", right_on="shuttle_id")
    model_input_table = rated_shuttles.merge(
        companies, left_on="company_id", right_on="id"
    )
    model_input_table = model_input_table.dropna()
    return model_input_table


import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# the below function uses plotly.express
def compare_passenger_capacity(preprocessed_shuttles: pd.DataFrame):
    fig = px.bar(data_frame=preprocessed_shuttles.groupby(["shuttle_type"]).mean().reset_index(), x="shuttle_type", y="passenger_capacity", )
    return fig
```

**pipeline.py**

```
from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, node
from kedro.pipeline.modular_pipeline import pipeline

from .nodes import create_model_input_table, preprocess_companies, preprocess_shuttles, compare_passenger_capacity


def create_pipeline(**kwargs) -> Pipeline:
    return pipeline(
        [
            node(
                func=preprocess_companies,
                inputs="companies",
                outputs="preprocessed_companies",
                name="preprocess_companies_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=preprocess_shuttles,
                inputs="shuttles",
                outputs="preprocessed_shuttles",
                name="preprocess_shuttles_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=create_model_input_table,
                inputs=["preprocessed_shuttles", "preprocessed_companies", "reviews"],
                outputs="model_input_table",
                name="create_model_input_table_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=compare_passenger_capacity,
                inputs="preprocessed_shuttles",
                outputs="shuttle_passenger_capacity_plot",
            ),
        ],
        namespace="data_processing",
        inputs=["companies", "shuttles", "reviews"],
        outputs="model_input_table",
    )
```

Reference:
https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/visualise_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed wrong arguments to pipeline.
After I deleted the below three lines of code, it worked.

```
namespace="data_processing",
inputs=["companies", "shuttles", "reviews"],
outputs="model_input_table",
```

Here is corrected code:

**pipeline.py**

```
from .nodes import create_model_input_table, preprocess_companies, preprocess_shuttles, compare_passenger_capacity


def create_pipeline(**kwargs) -> Pipeline:
    return pipeline(
        [
            node(
                func=preprocess_companies,
                inputs="companies",
                outputs="preprocessed_companies",
                name="preprocess_companies_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=preprocess_shuttles,
                inputs="shuttles",
                outputs="preprocessed_shuttles",
                name="preprocess_shuttles_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=create_model_input_table,
                inputs=["preprocessed_shuttles", "preprocessed_companies", "reviews"],
                outputs="model_input_table",
                name="create_model_input_table_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=compare_passenger_capacity,
                inputs="preprocessed_shuttles",
                outputs="shuttle_passenger_capacity_plot",
            ),
        ],
    )
```

[image]